# Passing Props from a fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Lets say I have my app.js with a NavBar component that has Link to each page path.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <header>
          <NavBar />
        </header>
        <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My home component will do a fetch to get details i need for the Home, Contacts & Profile component like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function Home() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getView() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("https://personalapi.amazonaws.com/default/getview", {
       method: "POST", 
       headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: {
          data: "ti"
        }
      });
      setData(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    getView();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  },[]);

  return (
    isLoading ? <div> Loading...</div> :
    <div>
     // put some of the data object here. 
    </div>
  );
};


export default Home;
```

How would I get the other parts of the data object to pass to my other components (Contacts, Profile). I am new to react router, so i am not sure how it works but I am getting the hang of React Hooks. Any guidance or direction on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can do the same for other components or if you are looking for data sharing between components you should take a look at Redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but basically, I think just move your fetch up to the app level. Assuming this is data you want to persist throughout the lifespan of your app, call it in App.js and pass the information down via props to each of the sub components depending on what they need.

Alternatively, if this is a oversimplified example, but you plan to share this across a lot of components not necessarily nested in App.js, you may need to look into a state management framework.
Some examples could be redux or mobx.